# Linking Excel spreadsheet property records to cadastral basemap in QGIS using ERF numbers as the unique identifier

Tags: qgis, parcel, unique-id

How does one link land parcel polygons in QGIS to an Excel spreadsheet of property records, using ERF numbers as the unique identifiers?

Comment: Research [table join](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_table_joins.html)

Comment: Thank you BERA.